# Does Java guarantee that Object.getClass() == Object.getClass()?

Tags: java, class, jvm, identity, equality

I really do mean identity-equality here.

For example, will the following always print **true**?

```
System.out.println("foo".getClass() == "fum".getClass());
```

Comment: If a class (1) does not override the equals(Object) method; and (2) is not a subclass of a class that overrides the equals(Object) method then this class uses the equals(Object) method defined in the root Object class - which uses the == identity operator.

Comment: @emory: I think your comment is wrong. The `==` in this snippet always performs reference comparison, and the operator can not be overloaded to invoke `equals` instead. Also, `java.lang.Class` is `final` so you can't override its `equals`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, class tokens are unique (for any given classloader, that is).

I.e. you will always get a reference to the same physical object *within the same classloader realm*. However, a different classloader will load a different class token, in conjunction with the fact that the same class definition is deemed different when loaded by two distinct classloaders.

See [this earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026127/is-it-possible-to-use-instanceof-when-passing-objects-between-threads/3026141#3026141) for a demonstration of this.

Answer (score 17):

For two instances of class `X`,

```
x1.getClass() == x2.getClass()
```

only if

```
x1.getClass().getClassLoader() == x2.getClass().getClassLoader()
```

*Note: `Class.getClassLoader()` may return null which implies the bootstrap ClassLoader.*

Comment: Excellent way of putting it

Comment: @McDowell, Your last paragraph is wrong. `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader` is not the same as the bootstrap classloader. If `.getClassLoader()` returns null, it means that the class is loaded by the bootstrap classloader. `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader` will not return null.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

> The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.

If it was possible to return multiple instances, then

```
public static synchronized void doSomething() {..}
```

would not be thread-safe.

Comment: Another clue is that the javadoc says that `getClass` returns "_The_ Class object that represents the runtime class of this object" ... not "_A_ Class object ...".

Answer (score 4):

It is guaranteed per classloader, as stated in the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.5):

> First, the Java Virtual Machine determines whether it has already recorded that L is an initiating loader of a class or interface denoted by N. If so, this creation attempt is invalid and loading throws a LinkageError.

That is, if a class loader (L) tries to bypass default `Class` instances caching, and make the JVM load the `byte[]` definition more than once for the same class name (N), a `LinkageError` will be thrown by the JVM.

For example, implement a class loader that calls `defineClass(...)` each time `loadClass(...)` is invoked (bypassing default caching):

```
public class ClassloaderTest {

    private static final byte[] CLASS_DEF = readClassBytes();

    private static byte[] readClassBytes() {
        try {
            InputStream is = ClassloaderTest.class.getResourceAsStream("ClassloaderTest.class");
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];
            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            buffer.flush();
            return buffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

    private static ClassLoader createNonCachingClassloader() {
        return new ClassLoader() {
            @Override
            public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                if (name.equals("classloader.ClassloaderTest")) {
                    return defineClass(name, CLASS_DEF, 0, CLASS_DEF.length);
                } else {
                    return getParent().loadClass(name);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassLoader cl = createNonCachingClassloader();
        Class<?> cl1 = cl.loadClass("classloader.ClassloaderTest");
        Class<?> cl2 = cl.loadClass("classloader.ClassloaderTest");
        System.out.println(cl1==cl2);
    }
}
```

and this is what happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  classloader/ClassloaderTest$1): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "classloader/ClassloaderTest"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at classloader.ClassloaderTest$1.loadClass(ClassloaderTest.java:53)
    at classloader.ClassloaderTest.main(ClassloaderTest.java:64)
```

Cheers