# java: comparing classes with == or .equals(): is there a difference?

Tags: java, class, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Java guarantee that Object.getClass() == Object.getClass()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738919/does-java-guarantee-that-object-getclass-object-getclass)

I know you're supposed to use `equals()` in general, but is there any way two `Class<?>` objects could be equal with `equals()` but not equal with `==`?

edit: I am specifically looking to find out whether two class objects exist such that

```
Class<?> cl1 = ...
Class<?> cl2 = ...
cl1.equals(cl2)    ->  true
cl1 == cl2         ->  false
```

This does *not* seemed to be covered by the possible duplicate question. (which is closely related)

Also it may *not* be true that the class objects were obtained by `someObject.getClass()` -- it could be that one was the result of `Class.forName(...)` and the other from some series of reflective actions like [`Method.getReturnType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getReturnType%28%29).

Comment: Exact duplicate looks like. Jason -- to find out in what instances the == and .equals return false, follow the link posted by @Goran

Comment: To those of you who closed: could you please either reopen or point out where in particular there is a case where == returns false but equals() returns true?

Comment: Since `Class.equals()` is not implemented, `Class` uses the default implementation from `Object` which uses `==` for comparison. So for any two (non-null) `Class` references `c1` and `c2` `c1.equals(c2)` will return `true` **if and only if** `c1 == c2` is `true`.

Comment: @Joachim: thanks. *That* is the kind of answer I was looking for (is this documented in the Java language spec or somewhere?) -- I still don't understand why this question was closed.

Answer (score -2):

All objects have both identity (the object's location in memory) and state (the object's data). The == operator always compares identity. The default implementation of equals compares identity as well.

For a fuller explanation:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

Comment: That's not my question. My question is about `Class<?>` objects.