# Testing equality amongst class types in java

Tags: java

Should I test equality between two class type objects using the `==` operator or using a more reliable way like `Object.equals(Object)`

Example

`String.class == obj.getClass()` or `String.class.equals(obj.getClass())`

PS: I'm only interested in using class type comparison (not using the `instanceof` operator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997801/java-comparing-classes-with-or-equals-is-there-a-difference & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738919/does-java-guarantee-that-object-getclass-object-getclass

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as you don't have different classloaders in the JVM.
Each object in java has a corresponding `java.lang.Class` object and its loaded into JVM once regardless the number of actual instances of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are basically equal since `java.lang.Class` uses the standard implementation inside `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

And since `Class` is final you can't override that.

Note, however, that once you're working with different classloaders you might get two classes that are basically the same but different instances, i.e. `java.lang.String != java.lang.String` if both come from different classloaders (that particular example probably won't happen, it's just an illustration).

As a final note, you might want to use `equals()` anyways if the instance you're calling it on can never be `null` (and `String.class` won't be null). That way you're reinforcing the habit to use `equals()` over `==` and in the extremely unlikely case that `Class` will change its implementation of `equals()` at some point it's probably safer to use it right now.