# Java - Understanding the Class<?> type and what happen when invoking 'Type.class'

Tags: java, class, singleton

In Java you can write the following code:

`Class<?> stringClass = String.class;`

The run-time will assign a reference to a Class instance represents the type java.lang.String class.

My questions are:

1. Is it guaranteed by the JVM that a Class instance is a singleton per Java type?
2. If the answer to #1 is true - when the Class instance is being created? (- calling `getClass()` or `Type.class` or maybe when the Class loader is loading a Java type at the first time.)
3. What happens under the hood when invoking `Type.class`. I am asking since there is no static member called `class` in the code of-course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738919/does-java-guarantee-that-object-getclass-object-getclass), `Class` objects per type are
   unique, given that you have only one `ClassLoader`.  Different
   `ClassLoaders` can yield different `Class` objects for the same
   class definition.
2. The `Class` objects are created when the class is loaded by a
   `ClassLoader`, usually when the class is first referenced.
3. According to the [Java Language Specification, Section 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2), `Type.class` is a *class literal*, so nothing is being invoked; the class literal refers to the `Class` object.

Quoting the JLS from the section linked above:

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed
>   by a '.' and the token class.

and

> A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or
>   for void) as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class
>   of the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the expression `Foo.class` is compiled to a simple lookup of constant pool, at least on javac7. So `Foo.class` is probably loaded when this class is loaded.

I remember that's not the case in older versions of Java; `Foo.class` was compiled into something like `Class.forName("Foo")` and the loading was rather lazy and on demand.