# Copying Properties from one bean into another: Java

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am facing issue in copying properties from one bean to another.

I am aware about the `copyProperties()` which can be used here to copy from source bean to destination bean probably if both the beans are of same type. 
My issue here is that I want to copy first 50 properties on the first call and next 50 properties on the second call.

Is there any way in which I can copy first 50 configs only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it only by using `reflection`.

@Zhuinden made a good point to start with.

To make the approach usefull for arbitrary classes, create a Map `name -> field`:

```
Map<String,Field> asMap( Field[] fields ){
  Map<String,Field> m = new HashMap<String,Field>();
  for( Field f : fields ){
    f.setAccessible( true );
    m.put( f.getName(), f );
  }
  return m;
}
```

then use it like:

```
Map<String,Field> trg = asMap( target.getClass().getDeclaredFields() );

int counter = 50;

for( Field f : Source.getClass().getDeclaredFields() ){
  f.setAccessible( true );
  Field fieldTarget = trg.get( f.getName() );
  if( null != fieldTarget ){
    fieldTarget.set(target, f.get(source));
    counter--;
  }
  if( 0 == counter ) break;
}
```

Comment: This is a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please give me a sample or a hint? That would be really helpful!

Comment: @injecteer..Oh yes.. Thanks for the solution. I am working on Reflection for the first time and not much aware about its core. Apoplogies for bugging with silly questions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work using reflection (added an error check at the start as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/3738954/2413303 ):

```
if(source.getClass() != target.getClass())
{
    throw new RuntimeException("The target and source classes don't match!");
}

Field[] fieldSources = source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
Arrays.sort(fieldSources);
Field[] fieldTargets = target.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
Arrays.sort(fieldTargets);
//source and target class is the same so their fields length is the same

for(int i = 50*n; i < fieldSources.length && i < 50*n+50; i++)
{
    Field fieldSource = fieldSources[i];
    Field fieldTarget = fieldTargets[i];
    fieldSource.setAccessible(true);
    fieldTarget.setAccessible(true);
    fieldTarget.set(target, fieldSource.get(source));
}
```

Comment: main problem with this approach: it would work ONLY with the same classes or classes with exactly the same properties

Comment: @injecteer Indeed, but he said `if both the beans are of same type.`, so I went with that assumption.

Comment: A better question is whether you actually need to get the Fields twice, or if once is sufficient because they're the same type to begin with.

Comment: @Zhuinden.. when I am trying to get the declaredfield using array.sort() as above, I am get a compile time error- "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Field[]"

Comment: However, I am able to achieve it using copyProperties. But, my problem is that I want to copy properties in the batches of 50. With each call I will copy 50 properties. I am just trying to figure out an appropriate logic for copying 50 properties.

Comment: `for(int i = 50*n; i < fieldSources.length && i < 50*n+50; i++)`

Comment: fixed the compile time error, I assumed `Arrays.sort()` returns the array that was being sorted but apparently not.