# Java instanceof not match Double

Tags: java, casting

I have a `Value` Class and there is an `Object value` in it. I want to use the value as `String`, `Integer` or `Double`.

The `asDouble` method controls `instanceof` value object. If it is not `Double` or `Integer` returns `0`.

Generally it works but sometimes although it is `Double` `returns 0;`. I couldn't the reason of it.

When I debug I can see:

[image: you can check]

Here is my Value class

```
public class Value{
    public Object value;

    public Value(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Double asDouble() {
        if (this.value instanceof Integer || this.value instanceof Double) {
            return Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(this.value));
        } else {
            return 0.0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody explain where did I go wrong

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: You've got a class called `Double` somewhere that isn't `java.lang.Double` or you've got multithreaded code modifying `value` while you read it.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? You are missing the input data that leads to this "bug", we need it to reproduce the issue. Otherwise we can only guess what the reason is. Probably you only thought you entered a `Double` to `value`, but did enter a different object. Like a `String` maybe `"0.2"` instead of just `0.2`.

Comment: From your image it may seem that you have happened to nest two `Value` objects inside each other, only the inner one containing a `Double`. So `this.value` is a `Value`, not a `Double`, so the `else` part is executed.

Comment: Instead of checking explicitly for the types Integer or Double, you could just check if it is `Number` then call `.doubleValue()` to get the value as a double.

Comment: @OleV.V. agree - a `Value` instance inside another `Value` indeed seems to be what's shown in the hover.

Comment: Really, you could make life easier if you wouldn't accept all `Object`s but just the three types you want. Then it can't ever happen that you accidentally add something wrong. And depending on the specific usage it might even be better to use some more specific container class instead. Using `Object` is rarely a good idea, you throw away all compiler-help.

Comment: Agree with killjoy's comment above. If it's already a double, then get the double value. Converting it into a string and then back into a double will lose precision and lower performance and increase memory usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer: Details matter.

Some info: The `value` class instance variable (also-known-as property or member variable) is a class named `Value`.
Since the class `Value` is neither the `Integer` nor the `Double` class,
the else branch will always execute.

The `Value` class also has a member variable named `value`,
which,
in your example, 
has a type of `Double`.

In the screen shot you included,
the `Value` object has its `value` member variable set to a "thing" which also has the type `Value`.
I know this because the dialog shows "value= Value (id:82)".

Answer (score 2):

first at all, i agree with [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v)s, [killjoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351110/killjoy)s and [david a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44355/david-a)s comments.

your screenshot shows a `Value`-Object holding another `Value`-Object in its `value`-property

the comments and a possible solution are summed up in the following example-class

```
public class Value {
    // visibility should be private
    private final Object value;

    // to be more type-save 
    // and to restrict
    // this.values instance-type to Double, Integer and/or String
    // provide three public constructors
    public Value(final Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Value(final Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Value(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double asDoublePrimitive() {
        if ((this.value instanceof Number)) {
            return ((Number) this.value).doubleValue();
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

    public Double asDoubleObject() {
        if ((this.value instanceof Number)) {
            return Double.valueOf(((Number) this.value).doubleValue());
        }
        return Double.valueOf(0.0);
    }
}
```

be aware that neither your nor my code consider the case that `this.value` is an `instanceof` `String`

Comment: There's an unnecessary object creation in `asDoubleObject()` in the case when `value instanceOf Double`. In that case, I would simply return `(Double) value`.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` check applies to full class definiton which includes the `ClassLoader` that loaded the class. Probably `this.value` was loaded by different `ClassLoader` and the check fails. You can confirm by trying:

```
ClassLoader cl1 = this.value.getClass().getClassLoader()
ClassLoader cl2 = Double.class.getClassLoader();
if (cl1.equals(cl2)) {
   ...
}
```

Although this can get even more trickier with parent-child relationships between `ClassLoader` objects [this answer provides a good example when `instanceof` fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3026141/1602555).

The other options is that your `Double` is not a `java.lang.Double` but that would be surprising.