# Class extends another class and implements interface in java can be casted to anyd of these types?

Tags: java, spring, types, interface, javabeans

I have spring bean like:

```
 <bean id="testBean" class="TestBean"
  ......
  <property name="resolver" ref="resolver"....
```

---

```
class Resolver extends BaseResolver implements IManagementInterface
```

in class TestBean setter:

```
 public void setResolver (IManagementInterface resolver) {
 this.resolver=resolver;
 ...
```

But when I run I receive exception:

> Cannot convert value of type Resolver to required type IManagementInterface.

But this seems not correct - because `Resolver` is also type `IManagementInterface`. What the sense of this error? Or may be I should clean install all my project?

Comment: Can you post `<bean id="resolver" />` complete definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a clean install first. If this doesn't make the problem disappear, you might be experiencing a classloader problem. If your `Resolver` instance (and the corresponding class declarations) was loaded by a different classloader than `TestBean`, it belongs to a different classloader realm, and it (or specifically its super interface `IManagementInterface`) is thus seen by the JVM as a completely different type from the `IManagementInterface` parameter type of `TestBean.setResolver`. So one can't be cast to another.

See [this earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614989/brainstorming-weird-jpa-problem-possibly-classpath-or-jar-versioning-problem/2615014#2615014) for a way to verify whether or not this is the root cause.